# Load files content

Tags: php, css, content

I would like to load a css file in my Wordpress plugin by php. First I tried file_get_contents:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(plugins_url('assets/css/fonts.css', __FILE__ ));
```

But than I get this error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

I noticed that one has to enable Allow_url_fopen in php.ini (but I also read about this being a security risk).

Is there a WordPress function to load e.g. a txt file and store its content in a variable?

**EDIT:**
I would like to parse a CSS file and get all its font-families.

```
<?php
function my_fonts() {
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/fonts.css');
    $rows       = explode("\n", $stylesheet);
    array_shift($rows);

    $fonts = array();

    foreach($rows as $row => $data)
    {
        // Find all available font-families
        $regex = '#font\-family:(.*)#';
        preg_match($regex, $data, $output);
        if($output){
            $font = str_replace(array('font-family:', '\'', ';'), '', $output[0]);
            $fonts[] = $font;
        }
    }

    // Remove dublicates
    $fonts = array_unique($fonts);

    print_r($fonts);
}
?>
```

Comment: Must the CSS be generated dynamically or are you just loading a CSS file so it can be linked in your generated HTML?

Comment: The CSS is static. I would look to parse the css to see if it contains a certain font-family.

Comment: Are you able to tell me what it is you're trying achieve in total? I might be able to advise you properly then.

Comment: @user90798 You should edit your question and add full details about what you want to do, to avoid answers that don't address your exact problem

Comment: Don't forget that the CSS might use the shorthand font property. And that @font-face rules let the author set arbitrary font names on fonts.

Comment: If I execute this file directly I will get an array with all the fonts. But when I try to execute it from within WordPress I will receive the above error message.

Comment: And is the relative path correct? We don't know the path to your code.

Comment: Problem here is the path. You want to take a look at [this blog post](wpkrauts.com/2015/the-guide-to-wordpress-path-and-urls/). If you find your solution there, please come back and answer your own question.

Comment: @kaiser Thank you very much for sharing this article. Great guideline!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I blocked my self out…
I had an .htaccess with password protection running that prevented the script from accessing the file.

Comment: Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your real problem in your **question**? As it currently stands, I need to close your question as being too localized, raising your flag count, which will lead to flags on badly researched or written future questions. That is something you will want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You should use WordPress's built in function `wp_enqueue_style` for loading styles.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: Yep. (I'm out of votes)

Comment: Generally yes, but this isn't what the OP wants to achieve (see his comments).

Comment: @TimMalone, ah. Well that's a completely different question now.